# Is it frowned upon to have a figure in the introduction of a Masters thesis?

Tags: thesis, graphics, introduction

Is it common practise/frowned upon to have a figure in the introduction chapter of a thesis?

The figure is not a 'picture', but a relatively small tree diagram that in my opinion shows the structure I am talking about more effectively than describing it in words.

I ask this question because I do not think it is common practise but also can't think of a good reason not to do it.

Comment: What does the style guide say? What did your supervisors say? What have recent theses in your department done?

Comment: Hi. i understand that these things often dictate what is allowed/not allowed. But at the end of the day it is my thesis that i need to feel proud about. My study leader clearly told me that all his guidelines are just that, and at the end of the day I decide what my thesis looks like. That may seem counter-intuitive as i asked the question here, but I was simply hoping to find other peoples view on the subject (-:

Comment: OK, but this isn't the place to solicit opinions.

Comment: I am sorry but I can literally not think of a more valid platform to ask such a question.

Comment: Whatever you do, [don't do this](http://neurodojo.blogspot.it/2014/03/maybe-these-graphical-abstracts-could.html) :-)

Comment: @TobiaTesan: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about the blogpost, but I'd have expected to find the images pointed out in the blogpost in the actual linked publications (as a "teaser image" maybe, or whatever "graphical abstract" is supposed to mean)? I opened a few of the papers from ScienceDirect, but none contained any of the graphics shown in the blogpost. Thus, it's not quite clear to me what "don't do this" actually suggests not to do.

Comment: @QRMapper: the images have since been removed by the publisher as a result of the controversy sparked, so that's probably why you don't see them in a freshly downloaded copy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a graphic clearly gets across the message then why not use it? Just check what the regulations specify though,

To elaborate a bit more you need to think about what the introduction is for. If it is  intended as an executive summary then a diagram that summarises the work could be very effective. If however it is setting the context of the work then I find it difficult to see how a diagram would help.

Answer (score 10):

Having a figure in an introduction is a common practice, and one that I strongly recommend.  Images are very good at conveying some ideas and relationships, and are also good for catching the eye and helping pick out key elements of a document (i.e., the things the author thinks are important enough to illustrate).  There is nothing special about an introduction that means it should be image-free, especially in a thesis where there is a whole chapter dedicated to it.

Yes, some people do not put figures in their introductions.  Indeed, some people don't put any figures in their scientific writing, and I really hate reading the documents that they produce.